# Is there a PHP SDK to pull the on-chain information in Solana?

Tags: sdk

There's a huge community of developers who build in PHP language. Is there a plan to build PHP SDK apart from JS SDK as well? Especially to pull on-chain data?

Update:
Howrare created a PHP SDK to Helius; which is very useful https://github.com/HowRareIs/helius-php-sdk

There's a Solana SDK https://github.com/verze-app/solana-php-sdk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [Solana PHP SDK](https://github.com/verze-app/solana-php-sdk) available that is currently not actively maintained.

You can use it today to pull on-chain transaction and account data.

Comment: Worth noting that the underlying mechanism to pull data from the chain is the [JSON RPC API](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api). This SDK is just a wrapper around that. As such, you can always use the JSON endpoints directly from PHP if the SDK is deficient in certain areas (or contribute to it!).

Comment: @yamen That helps! I'll dig in and start using the API. Not planning to use it for any serious purpose. Just trying to play around.